# How to define an isomorphism between $^\omega\omega$ and $\omega^\omega$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

Let $^\omega\omega$ be the set of all functions $x: \omega \to \omega$. Define $A = \{x \in ^\omega\omega \; | \; x \text{ has finite support}\}$, where by "finite support" I mean that the set $\{x(n) \; | \; x(n) \not= 0\}$ is finite. Finally, define $\prec_A$ as $x \prec_A y \iff x(n) < y(n)$ for the greatest $n \in \omega$ on which $x, y$ differ (it's not difficult to see that such an $n$ exists). It's rather easy to see that $\langle A, \prec_A \rangle$ is a well-order, whence, by Mostowski Collpase, it follows that it is isomorphic to an ordinal $\gamma$. My problem now is: how do I show that $\gamma = \omega^\omega$? I tried to define directly an isomorphism between $\langle A, \prec_A \rangle$ and $\omega^\omega$, but couldn't get very far. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to write titles that has to do with the content of the question, and not set up a confusion to possible readers.

Comment: Well, do you have any suggestions for amendments?

Comment: For starters the sets in the title do not match the sets in the question. ${}^\omega\omega$ is uncountable. How could it be isomorphic to a countable ordinal?

Comment: My problem was that I didn't know how to phrase the set in question; hence why I asked for a suggestion in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Show that for every $n\in\omega$, $\omega^n$ embeds into $A$, and that $A$ itself embeds into $\omega^\omega$.

Comment: Do I have to define the embeddings recursively?

Comment: Some are easy to do directly, some may be easier to do using recursion.

Comment: I think I got the idea behind the first embedding, but I'm not sure about how to define it formally. Each function in $A$ will be a set of $\omega$ pairs of the form $\langle n, m \rangle$ for $n, m \in \omega$, right? So we $\omega^0 = 1$ to the set of pairs $\langle n, 0\rangle$, for $\omega$ we use the pairs $\langle 0, n\rangle$, for $\omega^2$ the pairs $\langle 1, n \rangle$, etc. Is that it?

Comment: Close, not quite. For $\omega^2$ we look at the pairs $\langle 0,n\rangle$ AND $\langle 1,n\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, yes. So, in general, for $\omega^n$ we use the pairs $\langle 0, m \rangle, \langle 1, m \rangle, \dots, \langle n-1, m \rangle$, right?

Comment: You may want to use different letters for these coordinates. Currently it seems as if you only consider finitely many pairs.

Comment: Right. Now, in the other direction, I send the set of pairs $\langle n, 0 \rangle$ (for $n \in \omega$) to $0$, the set of pairs $\{\langle 0, 1 \rangle, \langle 1, 0 \rangle, \dots\}$ to 1, etc., basically reversing the other procedure, correct? I'm still a little bit unsure about how to write that in a more formal way, though.

Comment: Perhaps a better method to do this direction would be to show that given $a\in A$ there is some $a'\in A$ such that $a\prec a'$ and the order type of $\{a\in A\mid a\prec a'\}$ is $\omega^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: As I said, the argument to me is now clear: there is a greatest $n$ at which the functions on that set will differ; hence, there will be, for each pair $\langle s, t \rangle$ for $s \leq n$ and $m \in \omega$, $\omega^n$ possibilities, i.e. we have $\omega^n$ functions in that subset. But I'm a little bit unsure about how to prove this more formally. Do I use induction on $n$? Or an informal argument is enough?

Comment: I suppose that you can use induction, and show that there is a natural isomorphism between these sets.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty in setting up the isomorphism. My idea so far has been to send the functions whose first pair is $\langle 0, m \rangle$ for $m \in \omega$ to $m$, then the functions whose second pair is $\langle 1, m \rangle$ ($m \in \omega$) to $\omega \cdot m$, etc., until eventually I send the function $a'$ to $\omega^n$. Is this in the right direction?

Comment: Okay, how do you define $\omega^n$? Recall that $\omega^0=1$ and $\omega^{n+1}=\omega^n\cdot\omega$. Use this knowledge to devise a way of finding a bijection.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, I'm really struggling to see this. My last thought has been something on this line: if I proceed by induction, I can show that there is a natural isomorphism from $\omega^0$ to a subset $A'$ of $A$ (namely, the empty set). From there, assuming that there is an $A' \simeq \omega^n$, I've been thinking of trying to set up an isomorphism by trying to show that $\omega^{n+1} \simeq \omega^n \cdot \omega \simeq A' \cdot \omega \simeq \omega \times A'$. Is it something along these lines?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: FInally! Thanks a lot, as always, you've been a great help.

Comment: I apologize for bothering you again, but I have one more doubt. We can index all the $A'$s by the $n \in \omega$ such that $\omega^n \simeq An$, right? Would it be correct to say that $\mathrm{type}(A) = \mathrm{sup}\{\mathrm{type}(An) \; | \; n \in \omega\}$? Or does this require a separate proof?

Comment: Saying things in general requires proof. But this is not a difficult one, since this is an increasing chain of sets, and you can easily show that for a set of ordinals (which is also an increasing chain of sets), the $\sup$ is the union.

Comment: I was thinking about showing that, for each $n \in \omega$, if $\mathrm{type}(A_n) < \mathrm{type}(A)$, then $\mathrm{type}(A_{n+1}) < \mathrm{type}(A)$, whence it follows that $\mathrm{type}(A) = \mathrm{sup}\{\mathrm{type}(A_n) \; | \; n \in \omega\}$. But your comment made me think about another line of thought: $\mathrm{type}(A) = \mathrm{type}(\bigcup\{A_n \; | \; n \in \omega\}$. Is it the case that $\mathrm{type}(\bigcup\{A_n \; | \; n \in \omega\}) = \bigcup\{\mathrm{type}(A_n) \; | \; n \in \omega\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Some notes: First show that $^n
\omega$ is isomorphic to $\omega^n$, the show that all elements of $^n\omega$ are larger that elements of $^m\omega$ for $n >m$.